# What are the conditions for a path-connected compact set in the euclidean plane to have a path-connected boundary?

Tags: general-topology, compactness, path-connected

If I have a path-connected compact set of points in $\mathbb{R}^2$, what are the conditions for such a set of points to have a path-connected boundary?

Comment: I think a necessary and sufficient condition is that each connected component of the interior of the set be simply connected. This seems obvious to me, but it doesn’t seem easy to get a clean proof.

Comment: @Knaus I don't think that's sufficient.  For example, take a convex polygon (including interior) and glue to each side a region bounded by a topologist's sine curve (including the limiting segment on the $y$-axis, to make it closed).  The overall region and its interior are both contractible, but paths on the boundary cannot cross the pathological parts.

Comment: Good point! I was probably just visualising a CW-complex.